# Bad Request while RestTemplate Testing

Tags: java, spring, http, oauth

I have the problem, that, when I test my test application with maven, that it says `400 Bad Request`. I use oauth2 with basic authentication and grant_type `password`. If I do the authentification with programs like Postman. It works. But if I add the Basic-Authentification with Http-Headers I get bad request.

I tried to remove the `HttpHeaders()` object from the HttpEntity, then I get `401 Unauthorized`. I tried to put the encrypted headers manually in the `HttpHeaders()` object, but that gets me `400 Bad Request`, too. If I do the Request with `Postman`, select `POST` as method and `Basic Auth` as Authentication with `username, password, grant_type` as Body(JSON) it works.

So this is my Testing Class
    @SpringBootTest
    public class TestAppApplicationTests {

```
    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();


    @Test
    public void testOauthToken(){

        String plainCreds = "client:topsecret";
        byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
        byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
        String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);

        Object oauthRequest = new OauthRequest("Lukas", "test123", "password");

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Authorization", "Basic "+ base64Creds);
        HttpEntity<Object> reqData = new HttpEntity<>(oauthRequest, headers);

        ResponseEntity<Object> entity  = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/oauth/token", HttpMethod.POST,
            reqData,
            Object.class);

    }


}
```

This is my `OauthRequest` class

```
@Data
public class OauthRequest {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String grant_type;

    public OauthRequest(String username, String password, String grant_type){
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.grant_type = grant_type;
    }
}
```

I want to get the `access_token` and the `refresh_token` from the Server.

Edit: I have a not working repository here, if you want to know more about the code: https://github.com/precodeeu/test-spring-oauth

Edit²: If I put a raw json string in it, it doesnt work neither.

```
    OauthRequest oauthRequest = new OauthRequest("Lukas", "test123", "password");
    String json;

    try {
        json = mapper.writeValueAsString(oauthRequest);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        HttpEntity<Object> reqData = new HttpEntity<>(json, headers);

        ResponseEntity<Object> entity = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/oauth/token", HttpMethod.POST,
                reqData,
                Object.class);

    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Edit³
I just noticed, that the contenttype should be `Application_form_urlencoded`

Solution:
I have updated the code and build a Stringbuilder

@SpringBootTest
public class TestAppApplicationTests {

```
private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();


private String UrlEncodedBuilder(List<String[]> list){
    String returnString = "";
    for(String[] param : list){
        returnString+=param[0]+"="+param[1]+"&";
    }

    return returnString;
}

@Test
public void testOauthToken() {

    String plainCreds = "client:topsecret";
    byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
    byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
    String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);

    List<String[]> formData = new ArrayList();

    formData.add(new String[]{"username", "Lukas"});
    formData.add(new String[]{"password", "test123"});
    formData.add(new String[]{"grant_type", "password"});

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);
    HttpEntity<Object> reqData = new HttpEntity<>(UrlEncodedBuilder(formData), headers);

    ResponseEntity<Object> entity = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/oauth/token", HttpMethod.POST,
            reqData,
            Object.class);


}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, investigate how exactly your request looks like and compare it to the one that works.
Also check the response body in case of 400 code, body might contain some hints.

Comment: Hey mate, I just made the mistake to submit application/json and not application/x-form-urlencoded. Now I have build a Stringbuilder and it works. I Post my solution here.